# exec in python fail after converting python2 code to 3 with 2to3

Tags: python-3.x, exec

I had the previous working code in my script, and it was working well in python2.

```
exec("x = args.%s" % protocol)
```

the  `x` variable was then used after affectation. After the conversion to python3 with the 2to3 tool, this single line does not works anymore, with `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`  failure at runtime.

If I manually set in the script the right value for x, it works, proving the exec failed.
I find it difficult to debug, can you help me?

replace the faulty line with hardcoded value proved it worked.